# Массив структур в json

Tags: golang

Есть такой код:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "io"
)

type User struct {
    id int
    name string
    email string
}

func index(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request)  {
    response.Header().Set("Content-type", "json")

    users := getAll()

    responseData := map[string][]*User{
        "data": users,
    }
    jsonResponse, _ := json.Marshal(responseData)
    io.WriteString(response, string(jsonResponse))
}

func getAll() []*User  {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:@/testexample")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    rows, err := db.Query("select id, `name`, email from users")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    users := make([]*User, 0)
    for rows.Next() {
        user := new(User)
        err := rows.Scan(&user.id, &user.name, &user.email)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        users = append(users, user)
    }
    if err = rows.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    return users
}

func main()  {
    http.HandleFunc("/", index)
    http.ListenAndServe(":9000", nil)
}
```

Но на выходе получается `{"data":[{}]}` , хотя, если сделать, например, вот так `fmt.Println(users[0].name)`, то выведется имя, так что массив не пустой. Если же сделать так:

```
jsonResponse, _ := json.Marshal(users)
fmt.Println(jsonResponse)
```

то выведется `[91 123 125 93]` - откуда это вообще?

> Ваш вопрос был помечен как возможный дубликат другого вопроса. Если
>   ответ на него не решает вашу проблему, пожалуйста, отредактируйте свой
>   вопрос и обозначьте отличия.

Как мы видим, вопрос "Массив структур в json", а не "json в массив структур", так что нет, это не дубликат.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, пакет `encoding/json`, как и любой подобный пакет, работает только с экспортированными полями структур. Так что

```
type User struct {
    ID    int
    Name  string
    Email string
}
```

Во-вторых,

> … выведется [91 123 125 93], откуда это вообще?

Это байты, в которые вы сериализовали структуры. Если вы хотите распечатать байты как строку, используйте

```
fmt.Printf("%s", b)
```